# How to find out the location of a doctest file when running nose?

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose, python-2.x, doctest

I am using python nose to run a bunch of doctests in subdirectories. The calling script is nose.cmd:

```
nosetests --with-doctest --doctest-extension=rst
```

(The doctests live in *.rst files.)

Example directory structure:

```
\nose.cmd
\__init__.py
\module1\__init__.py
\module1\mymod.py
\module1\mymod.rst
\module2\...
\module3\...
```

How can the path of the rst file be retrieved in the python code inside the rst file itself? For example in mymod.rst the usual `sys.path` and `__file__` give no information about the path \module1\ but I need that for the imports.

Of course I could introduce a constant into each rst file that contains its directory, but that's not what I prefer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I could not find a way to do it I decided to run the tests without nose.